# F# Equivalent of Enum.TryParse

Tags: enums, f#, tryparse

In C#, the following code is valid:

```
MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.DEFAULT;
if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(string, out myEnum))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
```

So I thought I would use this in F#. Here is my attempt:

```
let mutable myEnum = MyEnum.DEFAULT
if Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(string, &myEnum) then
    printfn "Success!"
```

But it complains

`a generic construct requires that the type 'MyEnum' have a default constructor`

What in the world does that mean?

Comment: I can't reproduce this if I change `MyEnum` for `System.DayOfWeek`. What's the definition of `MyEnum`? FYI you can remove the need for `mutable` by doing `let (ok, myEnum) = Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>(string)` instead.

Comment: How is your enum defined? I'm thinking you might be trying to parse a discriminated union as enum instead.

Comment: @scrwtp, you are totally right. I didn't realize there was a slight difference in how it is defined in F#. Had to look at https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/enum-types/ to understand. If you make this an answer, I will set it as "the answer."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a rather unhelpful (if technically correct) message that the compiler gives you if you try to parse a discriminated union value using `Enum.TryParse`.

More precisely, if you look at that function, you'll see that it's parameterized with a type that's constrained to be a value type with a default constructor. DU's meet neither of this criteria - this is what the compiler complains about.

When defining an enum in F#, unlike C#, you need to explicitly give each label a value:

```
type MyEnum = 
    | Default = 0
    | Custom = 1
    | Fancy = 2
```

Skipping the values would make the compiler interpret the type as a discriminated union, which is a very different beast.